# Can non-linear PDEs be classified as homogeneous if there are no stray terms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have begun learning PDEs. I was wondering if say the PDE below can be classified as homogeneous even though its non-linear. Every resource that I checked on the internet does never speak of nonlinear homogeneous equations. Homogeneity is spoken of mostly in linear PDE cases.

Ex:

$$u_t - u_{xxt} + uu_x = 0$$

Thanks!

Comment: The definition of an ODE to be homogeneous is that, if $u$ is a solution, then so is $c u$ for some constant $c$. That's not true in your example.

Comment: Because of the $$c^2$$ in front of the nonlinear term? Makes sense.